# Best method for parsing an HTML table on an intranet

Tags: javascript, parsing

So let me outline the data available to me and its format, my goals, and what I'd really like to get from you folks.

Firstly the **format of the data.**

Scheduling data is laid on in an HTML table, like this:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Name<td>
    <td> <td>
    <td> /*content*/ </td>
    <td> /*content*/ </td>
    <td> <td>
    <td> /*content*/ </td>
    <td> /*content*/ </td>
    <td> /*content*/ </td>
  </tr>
```

So essentially the first td cell contains the person's name, then each following cell represents a day of the week, starting with Saturday. If the cell is empty, they don't work that day. So on this example, this person would have Saturday and Tuesday off.

This page is only accessible once logged into the website with a unique user account. The names of the people will be different for each person logging in, but the format will remain the same.

**My goal** is to parse this data so I can import scheduling data to my own internal tool. I'm mainly familiar with Javascript so I may host this as a web application rather than a desktop application.

**My questions** for you guys are:

1) Can I parse and import this data using Javascript? Would XMLHttpRequest let me do this?

1a) Is it possible to use jQuery's $.getJSON to parse this table into a JSON object, when the tool I'll be running will not be on the same server, and this site does not offer up its data in JSON format.

2) If not other language can I use to do this? I intend to learn PHP, so would this be a good project for this?

Any guidance/resources/recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: i think XMLHttpRequest would fail because of the same origin policy. i'd look for a server-side solution (could still be javascript ;) )

Answer (score 0):

1: Yes, you can parse Html with Javascript, XmlHttpRequest is basically an Ajax call, you can't parse anything with it, just fetch the data that way.

1a: No, $.getJSON is just a shortcut to $.ajax() setting the datatype to JSON. You'll have to use the XML one to parse the html.

2: Most server side languages are able to fetch and parse Html. If not built-in then through packages/addons/plugins or other 3rd party utilities. Not sure if it's easiest to use js or php to do that. You'll have to pick your battles :)